# How to call setState in Apollo Query Render Props?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I'm trying to combine setState and Apollo Query to create an error at a top level component. I'm actually using React Context, but this gets the same point across.

```
setError = () => this.setState({ isError: true });

render() {
  return (
   this.state.isError ? <CustomError /> : (
   <Query>
     {({ loading, error, data }) => {

       // first error check
       if (error) { 
         this.setError();
         // this all works if I return <div /> right here, but that's kinda bad
       }
       // I also want to set an error in a child component
       <VeryComplicatedComponentThatCantBeInThisFile setError={this.setError}>
     })
   </Query>
   )
  );
}
```

Anyone know how to best accomplish this?

Comment: Can you please explain the approach you are trying to get? Calling set state inside render function is not recommended, Instead you can just call return the CustomError component (but I guess it is related to the parent component)

Comment: @galvan - Yeah, that's the simple solution. Essentially I want to be able to set an error anywhere in the children components. I'm actually using React's context api to avoid passing it as a prop though. Seems like query should really have some sort of onFetchComplete prop/allow async functions.

Comment: What about redux? why not set a state in redux and every child which need to be aware if error happens can listen to application state.

Comment: @galvan - Forgive me - I haven't actually used Redux that much (trying to use React Context). Won't I run into the same issue though with needing to setState/change the store value in a render method?

Comment: No, with redux you can watch for changes in the application state, and when the state is changed the component will get new props with the new state. Take a look at react-redux - using the 'connect' high order component

Comment: You can use context in side of Apollo query to pass the error to all components. If you're not using the state's isError in any other class method. Then just easily pass the error to provider and consume it in any component

Comment: @Marvin - could you elaborate? I don't see how I'd setstate of the context safely in response to a Query error since it's still technically inside the render.

Comment: First, why are you setting error In state? You already have error in render, ready to be transferred to any child component through context. In the error conditional branch, u can add the context provider there to send the value to all consumers

Comment: Don't bother setting state in render, since you already have the error here, just render whatever you want inside the if (error) block

Comment: @Marvin - Yeah, I can return the error for this component, but how would I do it in a child component that is consuming context? I thought consumer needs to be able to take in a set state callback hence why I have my state error conditional outside of all of this at the very top.

Comment: You can pass both to it in value

Comment: @Marvin - yep, but won't I still have the problem of the child component setting state in its render? I can't return the error page in the child (and that kinda defeats the purpose)

Comment: No you, can just use a condition to see if the error property is true and render whatever you want

Comment: No you, can just use a condition to see if the error property is true and render whatever you want

Comment: @Marvin - the error needs to be rendered at the top level is the problem. If I could just render based off error in children, this would be straight forward

Comment: U can also do this, but without setState in render. U already have the value in render

Comment: @Marvin - but I'd need to be able to update the error in the children if the children encountered an error?

Comment: In that case setError also. It'd become ((if state.error or error) show message)

Comment: @Marvin - but then we are back to square 1 with setting state in render

Comment: You're not calling setState in render, bit i

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue on caching form data with render props. Luckily it provides `onError` and `onComplete` callbacks so that you can set states there. Note these callbacks won't be triggered while it uses cache.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  setError = () => this.setState({ isError: true });
  handleQueryError = error => {
    this.setError();
  };
  handleQueryComplete = data => {
    this.setState({formData: data});    
  };
  render() {
    return (<Query 
      fetchPolicy="network-only"
      onError={this.handleQueryError}
      onComplete={this.handleQueryComplete}>
      {({ loading, error, data }) => {
        return <VeryComplicatedComponentThatCantBeInThisFile isError={this.state.isError}>
      }}
    </Query>);
  }
}
```